# Commit from the VS Code command palette

Tags: visual-studio-code

After a recent VS Code update (presumably the June 2022 update), committing via the command palette seemed to stop working for me. How can you commit a change to Git using the command palette?

Previously, I would use the command palette to start a commit as shown in the following image.

[image: Committing from the command palette]

Then (still inside the command palette), it would prompt me for a commit message. I'd type the message, then hit "enter" to submit the message. The commit would then be completed.

Now, I see the following file (presumably the commit message file).

[image: Commit message]

I can edit the file as much as I want (including adding a message on the top line). I can save the file. But no commit happens. If at any time I close the file, I see the following error notification.

[image: Commit error]

So with the new process, how can I create a commit from the command palette? Any way to get the old behavior back? I really liked it.

I know you can use the Git panel in the sidebar, but I'd much rather use the command palette.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable:

> You can disable this new flow, and fallback to the previous experience
> that uses the quick input control, by toggling the
> `git.useEditorAsCommitInput` setting. After the setting is changed, you
> will have to restart VS Code for the change to take effect.

from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_69.md#author-commit-message-using-an-editor

The rest of the release notes on this

##### Author commit message using an editor

This milestone you can now use a full text editor to author commit messages, whenever no message is provided in the commit input box. To use this new flow, click the `Commit` button without providing a commit message.

You now can author your commit message in the editor. To accept the commit message and complete the commit operation, either close the editor tab or select the `Accept Commit Message` button in the editor toolbar. To cancel the commit operation, you can either clear the contents of the text editor and close the editor tab, or select the `Discard Commit Message` button in the editor toolbar.

You can disable this new flow, and fallback to the previous experience that uses the quick input control, by toggling the `git.useEditorAsCommitInput` setting. After the setting is changed, you will have to restart VS Code for the change to take effect.

To use the same flow for git commit commands executed in the Integrated Terminal, enable the `git.terminalGitEditor` setting. After enabling the setting, you will have to restart your terminal session.